# Close reader before closing connection

Tags: c#, .net, datareader

Should you always close a DataReader before closing the connection, or is it okay to just close the connection? By just closing the connection does that effectively close the reader?

(This is for c#.net 3.5)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from making your intent clear, there is this from the Microsoft documentation ([Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

> You should always call the Close method when you have finished using
>   the DataReader object.

Comment: In my experience if you close the connection, but not the DataReader, you can get the error _The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool_.

Answer (score 0):

Close the DataReader as well.

imo. if it implements IDisposable , or has a .close() method or a similar construct that the documentation states you should call when you're done with this instance - do it. 
Don't rely on something else to take care of it for you - unless the documentation explicitly states that it does. For a DataReader/DbConnection - the docs doesn't mention anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to leverage the c# using statment which will call dispose() for you.  Here is a decent explanation.

[Using Statment](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx)